# How to Use GPS data to detect road direction while recording using GPS Logger in Android

Tags: android, gps, tracking

I want to detect road direction and add it as a parameter in my GPS logger to Differentiate Direct Road from opposite Road I think there is a formula using bearing or using compass .

Comment: You shold specify better what you want to do and post some code of yours to receive a better answer

Comment: There is no need to post code, just to specify what valu you exopect as road direction ? an angle 0 - 360° an d forward, backward marker?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `location.getHeading()` or sometimes called `location.getBearing()`.
This delivers an angle from 0 - 360 degrees, where 0 is north, 90 is east.

This delivers the direction the device is moving.
A GPS chip and the related smartphone APIs do not know any roads, it just knows a location, direction, speed. This works on roads and at sea, and in air.
I dont undestand why the word "road" is used together with a GPS logger.

Digital maps as used in navigation systems or inside of google maps use roads but not a GPS Logger.